# Do adaptors exist to connect SATA hard drives to M.2 slot

Tags: hard-drive, nas, freebsd, freenas, m.2

Do adaptors to connect a classical spinning hard drive, such as Seagate IronWolf NAS drives, to an M.2 slot exist?

I am looking to the motherboard ASRock A520M-ITX for an upgrade of my NAS/VM server. Currently, I have 3 drives and my case can support up to 6; but the motherboard with AM4 socket only supports up to 4 SATA 6 Gb/s ports.

I could use the only PCI 16x slot for a card adding SATA ports, but I would like to keep it free for a graphic card in the future. I was wondering if the M.2 slot on this motherboard could be connected to 1 or 2 additional NAS drives?

I found [this connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FE8NKC2) from another post on SU. Can someone confirm this is the correct item to connect one SATA drive to an M.2 slot? Do other options exist? Could I connect two drives/split the lanes?

Comment: Typically SAS interface cards would be used in a case like this.  There are also PCIe cards that mux SATA ports capability.  It’s impossible to verify the quality of that particular product

Comment: @Ramhound Yes but then I lose the only PCIe slot on the mini-ITX motherboard.

Comment: That’s likely already the case if either of those m.2 slots are NVMe

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure to follow. The description is as follow for this board: 1 x PCIe 3.0 x16, 4 x SATA3, 1 x Ultra M.2 (PCIe Gen3 x4 & SATA3). The M.2 seems to be both NVMe or SATA.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1568659/219095 // This question is sort-of off-topic. // M.2 offers _one_ SATA link.

Comment: Yes, the adapter you linked to, or a similar one, will likely work

Comment: A generic question like 'can I connect a SATA drive via an M2 SATA capable connector?' might well be on-topic. Specific for one model motherboard would not be.

PS: Many motherboard disable existing SATA ports or additonal PCI-e slots when you use the M2 slots. Check your motherboard manual carefullly.